# React Error {Massage : AxiosError: Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49920:14)}

Tags: reactjs

**React: Axios Network Error**

This is my first time using axios and I have encountered an error.

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from "axios"
import { useState } from 'react'
import './Books.css'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const Books = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      await axios
        .get("http://localhost:1000/api/v1/getBooks")
        .then((res) => console.log(res.data.books));
    };
    fetch();
  });

  return (
    <div className='main'>
      <div className='hedder'>
        <h4>Books Selection</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Books
```

I got This error

> Uncaught runtime errors:

ERROR
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49920:14)

ERROR
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49920:14)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/011dU.jpg)

help me to reslove this

Comment: Can you check the Network tab of the chrome?